# How to create two identical PHP phar-archives

Tags: php, phar

I'm currently trying to distribute software written in PHP via executible phar-archive. The main problem is that output archive always have different md5 sum in subsequent creation, even if source files are not modified.

This cause several issues while deploying application with ansible: phar-file is always "new" so it is impossible to mitigate some post-deploy actions in playbook even if file contents is actually unchanged.

Here is sample script I use to create archive.

```
<?php

$phar_file = 'out.phar';

$src = [ '1.php', '2.php' ];
$stub = <<<EOF
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
Phar::mapPhar('{$phar_file}');
include 'phar://{$phar_file}/1.php';
__HALT_COMPILER();
EOF;

@unlink($phar_file);

$p = new Phar($phar_file);

$p->startBuffering();

foreach ($src as $f) {
        $p->addFile($f);
}

$p->setStub($stub);

$p->stopBuffering();
```

Let's try it:

```
# php7 create-phar.php 
# md5sum out.phar
5e0cdadb7953af4f1a67a2a0852e3a85  out.phar
# php7 create-phar.php 
# md5sum out.phar
4c97e3f67cf6f168c317235bc18299ea  out.phar
```

Cmp tells, that there are two two bytes changed in header, also signature differs:

```
# cmp -l out.phar out.phar.old 
 140 157 120
 173 157 120
3721 163 236
3722   5 235
3723 247 137
3724 246 160
3725 267 145
3726  52 174
3727 366 230
3728  22 322
3729  34 357
3730  45 176
3731  53  62
3732 130 142
3733 276 110
3734  20 252
3735 176 151
3736 134 105
3737 236   3
3738  62  16
3739 334 142
3740 176 244
```

Is it possible to create binary equal phar-archive from the same sources and how?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not keep the phar file and only recreate it when changes HAVE happened

Comment: @RiggsFolly just to simplify things. The playbook flow is easy: git pull -> assemble archive -> copy to destinations -> restart application if needed. Ansible won't do my restart actions if file is unchanged.